# Android - Signed apk not running

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform, push-notification

I am getting strange error while running exported apk using Android Tool in eclipse. In app i am using parse notification. While i run app from eclipse  all are working file and if I export signed apk app crashes. Here is logcat code link -[Here is logcat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/092g4jyukaze9rk/logcat.txt?dl=0)

I am not able to upload logcat here therefore i share link for it

If I block parse notification code, all going fine,. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using proguard in your project ?

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi Yes I do.

Comment: proguard has changed your files, obfuscated code, you have to define proguard rules in your app accordingly

Comment: Please guide me, how i do this.

Comment: give me link which external libraries are you using.

Comment: I am using  9 jar. Here is -> 1.android-support-v4.jar,  2. bolts-android-1.1.3.jar,  3. httpclient-4.2.3.jar,  4. httpcore-4.2.2.jar,  5. httpmime-4.2.3.jar,  6. joda-time-2.0.jar,  7. Parse-1.9.1.jar,  8. picasso-2.5.2.jar,  9.volley.jar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306797/android-i-want-to-create-code-very-secure/35306955#35306955

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103168/discussion-between-hammad-tariq-sahi-and-coreand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution, replace your progaurd code with this on -

> -optimizationpasses 5
>   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -dontpreverify
>   -verbose
>   -optimizations
>   !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
>   -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
>   -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
> ## keep all classes that might be used in XML layouts
>
> -keep public class * extends android.view.View
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
>   -keep public class * extends android.support.v4.Fragment
>
> ## keep all public and protected methods that could be used by java reflection
>
> -keepclassmembernames class * {
>   public protected
>   
>    ;
>    }
>    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>    native
>    
>     ;
>     }
>     -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>     public
>     
>      (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
>      }
>      -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>      public
>      (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
>       }
>       -keepclassmembers enum * {
>       public static **[] values();
>       public static
>       ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
>       }
>       -keep class * implements
>       android.os.Parcelable {
>       public static final
>       android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
>       }
>
> # Keep source file names, line numbers, and Parse class/method names for easier debugging
>   -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
>   -keepnames class com.parse.** { *; }
>
> ## Required for Parse
>
> -keepattributes *Annotation*
>    -dontwarn com.parse.**
>    -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
>    -dontwarn android.support.v4.app.**
>    -dontwarn com.android.volley.**
>    -dontwarn com.activate.gcm.**
>    -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
>    -dontwarn org.joda.**
>    -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**

Answer (score 0):

please check this.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepnames class com.parse.** { *; }

 # Required for Parse
 -keepattributes *Annotation*
 -keepattributes Signature
 -dontwarn android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
 -dontwarn android.app.Notification
 -dontwarn com.squareup.**
 -dontwarn okio.**
```

**Also add this**

```
   -keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
   -keep class com.parse.** { *; }
   -dontwarn com.parse.**
   -dontnote com.parse.**
```

Let me know if it did not solve your problem :)

Comment: add these lines in proguard-rules.pro file

Comment: Added but still facing same issue.

Comment: because this is just to give you an idea :) its not complete configuration. you have to visit each library at github and see proguard rule for that library and add in this file.

Comment: other library working fine in progaurd, only parse getting error.